# Attempting to create a custom List Class with Constructor

Tags: c#, list, class

I'm trying to create a customized list class with a constuctor that has a string parameter.

I have a string field that has several values imbedded within it.  If it were simple, I could just to a Split() but the string has to be analyzed to split it into it's various components.  I though I could just create a custom List class and do the splitting in the constructor.

```
Public ComponentList<T> : List<T> where T: Component
{
    Public ComponentList<T> (string componentString)
{}
}
```

When I try and create the constuctor, c# throws an error on the parameter - tuple must contain at least two elements.

Why does this need to be a tuple?  I just want to pass w string.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post the actual code that produces the error you describe. You can edit your question and paste the code into your question. When the above code is converted into valid C#, it compiles.

Comment: This doesn't look like real code that was typed in Visual Studio or some other IDE. `Public` is capitalized, which won't compile, and the class declaration is missing the word `class`.

Comment: @ScottHannen And he's got `<T>` in the constructor.

Comment: Yeah the problem was the <T> in the constructor.  Sometimes you just can't see what you're staring at.

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to remove the `<T>` from the constructor:

Like this:

```
public ComponentList(string componentString):base()
{
}
```

Also notice how I added the `:base()` that calls the constructor of the base class.

And you could even pass parameters to the base class that way you can have multiple constructors that match other constructors on your base class.

For example you could have a constuctor that passes the initial capacity

```
public ComponentList(string componentString, int capacity):base(capacity)
{
}
```

Comment: `:base()` isn't needed. The parameterless base class constructor (if any) is called automatically, if no base class constructor is called explicitly. I'm wondering what his real issue is, because I couldn't find a way to make his pseudocode give me any errors about tuples.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you, Darkonekt.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I agree... But my answer is meant to illustrate the possibilities.  To show some useful information that might make it easier for others to understand.  I know calling the parameterless constructor is a little verbose; but it gets the idea across.  And that is why I also posted a base constructor that takes an actual parameter.

Comment: @EdPlunkett by the way I was able to get the tuple compilation error by adding <T> to the constructor.....

Comment: @Darkonekt Good catch, now I see it. I was only looking at the red squiggles in the editor. I'll remember that.